# spy Mockito with Coroutines

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a class with the name ViewModel.

When the variable `shouldCheck` change, the function open is called.

```
class ViewModel {

    val shouldCheck = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    
    val check by lazy {
        shouldCheck.switchMap {
            liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
                open()
                emit(true)
            }
        }
    }

    fun open(){
        println("I am open")
    }
    
}
```

I create a simple test. but verify function open is failed

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class CoroutineTestRule(private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()) : TestWatcher() {

    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

}


    @get:Rule
    val coroutineScope = CoroutineTestRule()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        viewModel = spy(ViewModel())
    }
    @Test
    fun checkTest() =  runBlocking {
    
        // observe
        viewModel.check.observeForever {
            // ...
        }
    
        // Action
        viewModel.shouldCheck.value = true
    
        // Expected
        verify(viewModel, times(1)).open()
    
    }
```

in debug mode, I checked that and function open is called.and print `"I am open"`, but I have this error.

```
Wanted but not invoked:
viewModel.open(); 
However, there were exactly 2 interactions with this mock:
```

if I remove switchMap and `liveData(Dispatchers.IO)` test passed.
but I need it there.

Comment: Are you mocking the `ViewModel` right? How does that setup look like?

Comment: @NagyRobi I edit the question, I setup the viewModle by spy, you can see now

Comment: And is `open()` the function of `MyIdentifyPayViewModel()` or some inner function?

Comment: yes, open() function in the ViewModel, I change the code. I think the issue from switchMap or coroutines

Comment: @NagyRobi I update the code again

Comment: Could you try using `runBlockingTest()`?

Comment: @NagyRobi I use runBlockingTest and runBlocking, but nothing change, the error has still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google:

[image]

My advice would be to inject the dispatcher like this:

```
class MyViewModel(private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher)
```

And use the `TestCoroutineDispatcher` within your tests, this might help

Comment: I use this class CoroutineTestRule

Comment: If I'm correct only your Main dispatcher will be replaced with `TestCoroutineDispatcher`, open will still run on the `IO`

Comment: I know this error related to switchMap. can you see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444828/spy-mockito-for-map-or-switchmap-livedata